# multiple virtual inheritance: why isn't the class method ambiguous?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I came across the following c++ code in an online test.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 2) : m_n(n) {}

public:
    int get_n() const { return m_n; }
    void set_n(int n) { m_n = n; }

private:
    int m_n;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(char c = 'a') : m_c(c) {}

public:
    char get_c() const { return m_c; }
    void set_c(char c) { m_c = c; }

private:
    char m_c;
};

class C
    : virtual public A
    , public B
{ };

class D
    : virtual public A
    , public B
{ };

class E
    : public C
    , public D
{ };

int main()
{
    E e;
    C &c = e;
    D &d = e;
    std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n();

    c.set_n(3);
    d.set_c('b');
    std::cout << c.get_c() << d.get_n() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs a2a3 but I don't get it. Why does this run at the first place isn't the class B methods ambiguous? Also class E is not virtually inherited.

Comment: Why would `B` s methods be ambiguous? It does not overload anything, so there really is no chance for it to be ambiguous?

Comment: Why would you want `E` to be inherited? By whom and what for?

Comment: "_Also class E is not virtually inherited_" class `E` is not inherited at all here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `c` has type `C&` and `d` has type `D&`, there's no ambiguity - both `C` and `D` have exactly one `B` subobject.

(`c` and `d` literally refer to the respective subobjects of `e` - they don't refer to "`e`, but under a different type".)

The reason that the output is "a2a3" and not "a2b3" or "a2a2" is that `A` is inherited virtually, so there is only one `A` subobject in `E` and thus only one `n` member.

The `C` and `D` subobjects have one `B` subobject each, and `d.set_c('b');` modifies the one in `d` but not the one in `c`.

Answer (score 5):

If you were to try `e.get_c()`, that would be ambiguous.

However, the `C` and `D` interfaces only contain one `B` each, and know nothing about each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are accssing methods of `C` and `D` classes via `c` and `d` references, there is no ambiguity. Try this

```
std::cout << e.C::get_c() << e.C::get_n() << std::endl;
std::cout << e.D::get_c() << e.D::get_n() << std::endl;

//line below will not compile because here access 'get_c' is ambiguous
//std::cout << e.get_c() << e.get_n() << std::endl;
```

here you will access methods of `C` and `D` classes directly via `e` instance. Now the last line is ambiguous because of call to `e.get_c()` and you have to specify either `C::` or `D::` prefix to resolve ambiguity on favor of `C` or `D` methods.

```
std::cout << e.C::get_c() << e.get_n() << std::endl;
std::cout << e.D::get_c() << e.get_n() << std::endl;
```

Note: there is no need to place prefixes before get_n() because `A` is a virtual base class, shered between both `C` and `D` in inheritance tree.